# Unhelpful message about uncorrect template with the play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Why do I get the following error in play?

```
Compilation error
not found: value title
In C:\tmp\var\hello-play-java\app\views\main.scala.html at line 5.
2@import helper._
3@import search.TermsQuery
4
5@(title: String, content: Html, myForm : Form[TermsQuery]) 
6
7<!DOCTYPE html>
8<html>
9<head>
10    <title>@title</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because obscenely, the arguments for a template should come before the import statements, even if they use the imports. Hopefully this saves someone else the 30 minutes it cost me.